# GraphQL Type Fields having same type as Parent (Cycle)

Tags: graphql

In this example 
https://graphql.org/graphql-js/constructing-types/

Is it possible for us to achieve Type referring back to its root | parent type? (manager field type referring back to userType)

```
var userType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'User',
   fields: {
     id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
     name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
     manager: { type: userType },
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Return fields as Thunk solved my issue.

```
var userType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'User',
   fields: ()=> {
     return {
       id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
       name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
       manager: { type: userType }
    }
   }
});
```